# how to use isset when click submit

Tags: php

I don't understand how to send the form variables using `isset` when we click on submit. When i click the submit button, a notice is appearing indicating:

> Undefined index: rollno in C:\xampp\htdocs\test7.php on line 8.

My intention is to update the details by clicking on submit and update using `isset` function and after updating return to the form again.

My code is here:

```html
 <html>
  <head>
   <style>
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="test7.php">
       <center>Enter Roll Number: <input type="text" name="rollno" required/></center><br>
          <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" /></center>
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

test7.php starts here

```html
 <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
       <?php
         include('connect.php');
         $rno=$_POST['rollno'];
          $sql="select * from stddetails where rollno='$rno'";
          $query=mysql_query($sql);
          $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
          if($count>0)
          {
             $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);

          }
        ?>
        <center><form method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Roll Number</td><td><input type='text' name='roll' value='<?php echo $row['rollno'];  ?>'  disabled /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Student Name</td><td><input type='text' name='sname' value='<?php echo $row['sname'];  ?>' size='80' /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Father Name</td><td><input type='text' name='fname' value='<?php echo $row['fname'];  ?>' size='80'/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>gender</td><td><input type='text' name='gender' value='<?php echo $row['gender'];  ?>' /> </td></tr>
                <tr><td>Aadhar</td><td><input type='text' name='aadhar' value='<?php echo $row['aadhar'];  ?>' /> </td></tr>
                <tr><td>SSC Htno</td><td><input type='text' name='ssc' value='<?php echo $row['sschtno'];  ?>' /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>SSC board</td><td><input type='text' name='board' value='<?php echo $row['sscboard']; ?>' /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>SSC Grade</td><td><input type='text' name='grade' value='<?php echo $row['sscgrade'];  ?>' /></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan='2'><center><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Update' /></center></td></tr>
           </table>
        </form></center>

      <?php
         if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
       {
          echo"success";
       }

      ?>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: **The `mysql` PHP extension is dead** -- Stop using the [`mysql_*()` PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). They are old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead. Read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/4265352) to learn more about why and how.

Comment: It's true but at work, sometimes we can't choose to use PDO because of legacy code... e.g. the boss tell to do that

Comment: Above my paygrade to convince your boss to go along with time and update his stuff... wait i dont get paid at all ... so my advise is for free :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143519/why-is-isset-postlike-not-working-when-i-click-on-submit-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on line 8 you must write:

```
$rno = isset($_POST['rollno']) ? $_POST['rollno'] : '';
```

instead of:

```
$rno=$_POST['rollno'];
```

That ternary operator `(condition) ? true : false` set the value for `$rno` after checked if the variable `$_POST['rollno']` exists.

Comment: Thanks for your help. undefined rno is rectified. when i entered the form and click submit button it is posting to form in test7.php. But when i click the update button in form in test7.php the inputs in the form are filled with <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: row in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test7.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />

Comment: Because `if($count>0)
          {
             $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);

          }` isn't necessary. Simple write `$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);` Then, the `$row` variable will be empty if there will be no data.

Comment: Thank you my friend. my problem is solved

Comment: another doubt please. in the form in test7.php all the inputs varaibles are getting by post method to isset except roll again. it was showing undefined variable here also.

Comment: See your code `                <tr><td>Roll Number</td><td><input type='text' name='roll' value='<?php echo $row['rollno'];  ?>'  disabled /></td></tr>` change from roll to rollno

Comment: sorry i didnt get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162990/discussion-between-pavan-and-user2342558).

Answer (score -1):

// try this ..

```
 if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["submit"])) {
        echo "Success";    
    }else{  
        echo "Unsuccess";
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Just as an explination.

Technically what happens is that the code is already being excecuted when you load the page. There is no check to tell it when it should happen. Thats what the `if(isset())` is for. It checks, as it states, that if there are variables present or that a certain action is happened, such as the submit button. Since your button is needed to do an update, you tell it, as @User2342558 states to check if that action has happened. If so, then excecute your piece of code. When the check isn't happening, your variables will be empty and causes problems.